# Will QTimer with mutex cause program to exit unexpectedly?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, mutex, qtimer

What we know:

- QTimer without the single-shot option will emit a timeout signal at a specific interval.
- Timeout will call a function when emitted.
- A mutex will lock a variable from being modified by another thread.

My question is:

Say I have a very timing consuming function F1 uses a variable A with a mutex in one thread. And, QTimer is running a loop calling function F2 which also uses A with a mutex in another thread. If F1 is running and A is locked, then F2 will wait for A to be unclocked. Will the QTimer stack a lot of F2 calls when F1 runs indefinitely?

Comment: Will it? Have you tried it?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: I just tried. It will not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Pyqt will handle it. Here are two example threads:

```
class test_thread(QThread):
    timer = QTimer()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.start)

    def run(self):
        print("call")
        global mutex
        global n
        mutex.lock()
        n = n + 1
        print(n)
        mutex.unlock()

    def process(self):
        self.timer.start(1000)

class test_thread1(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)

    def run(self):
        global mutex
        mutex.lock()
        while True:
            global  n
            n = n - 1
            print(n)
            time.sleep(1)
        mutex.unlock()
```

Two situations are tested:

1. test_thread1 without `time.sleep(1)`

   The "call" in test_thread will never be printed and the n is counting down.
2. test_thread1 with `time.sleep(1)`

   The "call" only showed up once and the n is counting down as well.

Comment: If test_thread1 is not started, n will be counting up as expected.